# Launching a project downloaded from the android open source project in eclipse

Tags: android, android-source, eclipse-adt

I'm just starting to developing for the android platform. I'm still in "reading lots of code" phase. I downloaded the source code from android's music player into eclipse, now I want to run it on the emulator but eclipse tells me that the "selection cannot be launched".
Is there something missing?
I used this tutorial to get the code: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html and the git repository is: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music

Comment: Do you mean it compiles fine with no error you try to launch the app via "Run As"  "Start As" it gives you that issue?

Comment: It gives me no chance to "run as" says "none applicable"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a project you have to put into the eclipse

first put you project in your workspace.

then go to Eclipse-> file-> import and find your project.

when you have your project into eclipse open AndroidManifest.xml file
and find the number of android:minSdkVersion.

Finally and go to... Eclipse-> Window-> Android SDK and AVD manager and create you SDK with the number of android:minSdkVersion

Now you are ready to run your application.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply, but there is no such tag as android:minSdkVersion in the manifest file, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: No sorry, but try this, Do you have SDK installer??? http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html read this to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#Manifest

Comment: I already read those articles, it's probably because it is a repository. I'll try to create a new project and copy file by file, it also ain't got the R file that might be the issue. Thank you anyway!